# Add tooltips to filters under the new navigation

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, new-nav

When I hover over the tabs, a tooltip clarifies what I'll be looking at:

[image]

Ahhh, there we go; "popular" will show "questions worth reading". However, when I want to filter by "show" and want to know what "recommended" means (since I don't know), there's nothing:

[image]

Perhaps a tooltip clarifying what this means would help.